# Deep copy char * array into struct?

Tags: arrays, c, char

This is likely a very beginner question so please go easy on me...

I have a struct array as follows

```
struct Data {
   int lineno;
   char* line[10];
}

struct Data datas[20] = {{ 0, NULL }};
```

I'm trying to deep copy a char * [] into an array element yet I keep getting seg faults.

I've attempted the following

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    strcpy(datas[slot].line[i], line[i]);
}
```

but this doesn't work.
I thought that my problem was attempting to copy null values in line so I tried the following

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    if (line[i])
        strcpy(datas[slot].line[i], line[i]);
}
```

but this doesn't work either.

Comment: Each `datas[slot].line[i]` needs to point to something.

Comment: Do I need to malloc a char * [] for each datas[slot].line?

Comment: you need, for example, for each `i`, to figure out the length of `line[i]` by `strlen` or by yourself, then do `datas[slot].line[i] = malloc(length_you_got)`...

Comment: but also be careful to take into account the extra char of length for the concluding 0 you have in a string...

Comment: Strlen is for strings no? I'm trying to copy an array of strings. But I will try to allocate the memory before copying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to allocate memory before copying the string. Most implementations support `strdup` to both allocate memory and copy the string:

```c
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    datas[slot].line[i] = strdup(line[i]);
}
```

If your implementation doesn't support `strdup`, you could create your own:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
char *StrDup(const char* str) {
    size_t len = strlen(str) + 1;
    char *res = malloc(len);
    if (res) memcpy(res, str, len);
    return res;
}
```

Comment: I tried this and still get a segfault...

Comment: @AnAssembler In that case, `line[i]` doesn't point at allocated memory either. How is `line` defined and initialized?

Comment: Yes that seems to be the case... Thank you

Comment: @AnAssembler You're welcome! Glad it helped!

Comment: The OIP's struct has an array of 10 char pointers. The OP's code loops with `i` from 0 to 19, and uses it to index into the `line` member array. This seems a reasonable cause of a segfault as well.

Comment: @Chris Good point. Yes, that may be an additional cause for problems.